# Why is my submit button relocated outside Django form when the form is reloaded from invalid post?

Tags: django, django-forms, form-submit, submit-button

I have a template which includes a ModelForm, a ModelFormSet, and a submit button which is supposed to submit all form data from both the Form and FormSet. The problem is, when I submit the data, if the data is invalid, sometimes the template will reload with the submit button relocated outside the form container - how does that even happen? - and though the user can edit the data in the forms to be valid, they are no longer able to submit the form(s). Also, the submit button is not floated. I use button with id "add_def_report" to dynamically add forms to the incident_formset (I add an "empty_form" to the incident_formset and change the ids). Thank you for any help!

Template:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">

{% crispy incident_form %}

<input type="button" id="delete_field_data" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Delete Field Incident Data">

<div id="form_set_class">
  {{ incident_formset.management_form }}
  {% for form in incident_formset %}
    {{form.non_field_errors}}
    {{form.errors}}
    {% crispy form %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<p>Add a part deficiency report for each component which needs repair or replacement</p>
<input type="button" id="add_def_report" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="Add Part Deficiency Report">

<div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
  <div id="incident___prefix__">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Part Deficiency Report</legend>
      {{incident_formset.empty_form}}
      <br>
      <input type="button" id='delete_incident___prefix__' class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Delete Part Deficiency Report" onclick="delete_def_report()">
    </fieldset>

  </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary custom-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.center-text{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

form{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

legend {
  float: left; /*allows for top margin */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#form_set_class{
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

#form_set_class *{
  display: block;
}

#add_def_report{
  text-align: left;
}
```

views.py:

```
def new_incident(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    incident_form = IncidentForm(request.POST)
    deficiency_formset = DeficiencyFormSet(request.POST)

    if deficiency_formset.is_valid() and incident_form.is_valid():
        incident_form.save()
        forms = deficiency_formset.save()
        for form in forms:
            form.save()
        return redirect('quality_dept:home')

    else:
        dict = {'incident_form': incident_form, 'incident_formset': deficiency_formset}
        return render(request, 'incidents/new_incident.html', dict)

else:
    incident_form = IncidentForm()
    formset_data = { 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '0',
                     'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
                     'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '20'}
    def_formset = DeficiencyFormSet(formset_data)
    dict = {'incident_form': incident_form, 'incident_formset': def_formset}
    return render(request, 'incidents/new_incident.html', dict)
```

forms.py:

```
class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IncidentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset("General Information", 'incident_id', 'qc_rep', 'date_filed'),
            Fieldset("Contract Data", "job", "contract", "unit"),
            Fieldset("Description", "description", "resolved", "resolution"),
            Fieldset("Field Incident Data", "field_incident", "gov_poc",
        "location_of_unit", "shipping_address", id="field_incident_fieldset")
    )
        self.helper.form_id = "incident_form"

    class Meta:
        model = Incident
        fields = "__all__"

class PartDeficiencyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PartDeficiency
        fields = "__all__"

DeficiencyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=PartDeficiency, form=PartDeficiencyForm, exclude=None, extra=0, max_num=20, can_delete=True)
```

Comment: Please show `IncidentForm` and `IncidentForm`. Passing `formset_data` for GET requests is unusual. Usually you would do `def_formset = DeficiencyFormSet()` for GET requests, and set the initial and max number of forms when you call [`formset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/formsets/#formset-factory).

Comment: @Alasdair I've added my forms.py module. Could you explain your comment further? I was modeling my formset off the Django doc, which gives this ex: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation. Later: "You may have noticed the additional data (form-TOTAL_FORMS, form-INITIAL_FORMS and form-MAX_NUM_FORMS) that was required in the formset’s data above. This data is required for the ManagementForm. This form is used by the formset to manage the collection of forms contained in the formset. If you don’t provide this management data, an exception will be raised."

Comment: The management form is only required for POST requests. If you do `def_formset = DeficiencyFormSet()` for a GET request, then the form is unbound so Django doesn't try to validate the form. It was just a comment - it doesn't explain why your form tag is in the wrong place. I can't immediately spot the issue, so I would experiment removing js/crispy form functionality to try to narrow down what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Alasdair Okay, but if I do deficiency_formset = DeficiencyFormSet(request.POST) after a POST, the formset should be bound at that point correct? And then the is_valid() method should return a list of forms? Because when I do submit a correctly filled form, I do not get forms from the formset--it is empty. Both of these problems--the submit button moving on invalid forms and the lack of forms in a valid formset--are confusing me very much. Especially the submit button--how does an element just walk out of a form/div?

Comment: The `is_valid()` method returns `True` or `False` depending on whether the submitted data is valid. I can’t explain the issue you are seeing in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I found a fix for the confusing behavior of the submit button - I enclosed everything within the form tags within a div. This apparently works, but does not technically answer my question because it does not explain *why* it happened. But I will post this as an answer to separate it from troubleshooting comments above. If I find an answer to the why, I will add it here.

Comment: this worked for me, but I'm also very curious why this works